# Table cells changing for single data entry

Tags: html, html-table

I am doing project by designing front end using html. I am using tables in order to create the partitions for different tags.

Problem: When I enter the static value for a cell, the cell size also changes.

Comment: I think we'll need a lot more detail in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `width` on `td`:

```
td {
  width: 100px;
}
```